# Sequence(isi m.math sample paper question)

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Suppose, $a>0$. Consider a sequence, 
 $a_{n} = n((ea)^{1/n} - (a)^{1/n})$ .
Is the sequence convergent? If it is, then what is the limiting value? 
I have applied Cauchy's 2nd limit theorem but fails. Plz help me

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$a_n=na^{1/n}(e^{1/n}-1) $$
$$=a^{1/n}\frac {e^{1/n}-1}{\frac {1}{n}} $$

when $n\to +\infty $, $1/n \to 0$.
using the well-known limit
$$\lim_{X\to 0}\frac {e^X-1}{X}=1$$

we find
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to+\infty} a^{1/n}=a^0=1$$